# JS- Como puedo acceder a los parametros internos del array?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objeto, javascript-metodo

Soy muy nuevo en JS y me esta costando acceder a los parametros internos del array packViajes - servicios.

Estoy intentando acceder con las funciones .find y .map .. pero se me esta haciendo imposible

Como es la sintaxis correcta?
(Aclaro que la variable eleccionServicios esta declarada globlamente
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
function seleccionarServicios() {

    let losServicios = packViajes.map((elServicio) => elServicio.servicio.item + " " + service.servicio.precio)
    alert(losServicios.join(" - "))
    

    losServicios = prompt("Desea comprar estos servicios? \n 1- Seguro \n 2- Equipaje \n 3- Siguiente")

    eleccionServicios = packViajes.find((elijeServicio) => elijeServicio.servicio.item == losServicios)
```

Comment: La estructura de packviajes está mal, la propiedad 'servicios' es un objeto al que le estas sobrescribiendo constantemente las propiedades item y precio, no se pueden repetir nombres de propiedades en los objetos, osea si se puede pero estas sobrescribiendo la propiedad y solo queda la ultima (planificacion premium). No pongas imagenes, pon packviajes como codigo.

Comment: Desde el momento que pones `losServicios = prompt("...")`, no sé qué pretendes que valga luego tu variable `losServicios` en el `packViajes.find((elijeServicio) => elijeServicio.servicio.item == losServicios)`... obviamente `losServicios` solo va a valer 1, 2 o 3, mientras que los valores de `item` son bien diferentes. Eso sin tener en cuenta el mapeo extraño que haces arriba, que de todas maneras no sirve de nada porque luego lo machacas con el valor del prompt.

Comment: Tengo 3 semanas en JavaScript. justamente lo que estoy buscando es ayuda con la sintaxis. El mapeo "extraño" que hago arriba, es para mostrar los parametros al usuario que pueda elegir... ¿¿Podrias darme una mano en vez de decirme que estoy haciendo todo mal??.. Ya se que hice casi todo mal, por eso busco ayuda xD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

claro, te explico, fíjate donde indico aquí, este sería tu ejemplo:

```
const packViajes = [
    {
        city: "Sidney",
        precio: 1200,
        servicio: { //<<- aquí
            item: "seguro", precio: "50", //<-y en estas lineas
          item: "seguro2", precio: "50"
        }
    }
]
function seleccionarServicios() {
 //--> la función tiene varios conceptos mal, pero tiene arreglo :)

    let losServicios = packViajes.map((elServicio) => elServicio.servicio.item + " " + service.servicio.precio)
    alert(losServicios.join(" - "))
    

    losServicios = prompt("Desea comprar estos servicios? \n 1- Seguro \n 2- Equipaje \n 3- Siguiente")

    eleccionServicios = packViajes.find((elijeServicio) => elijeServicio.servicio.item == losServicios)
```

Y esto sería bien, pero ten en cuenta que los datos que le pasas no cumplen lo que pides, así que es lo primero a cambiar, en cualquier caso, no tengo demasiado tiempo pero un par de ejemplos que te pueden venir bien:

```
const packViajes = [
    {
        city: "Sidney",
        precio: 1200,
        servicios: [
            {item: "seguro", precio: "50"},
          {item: "seguro2", precio: "50"}
        ]
    }
]
function seleccionarServicios() {
   let count = 1;
   const packViajesEditado = packViajes.map(
      (elViaje) => {
        console.log("aquí estamos recorriendo los viajes y podemos acceder a variables como city y a cada servicio");
        elViaje.servicios.map(
          (elServicio) => {
            console.log("ya estamos en cada servicio y podemos acceder a cada item");    
              elServicio.item = count.toString() + " - " + elServicio.item; 
              count = count + 1;
          }
        )
      }
    );
    //normalmente no tabulo de esta forma pero creo que se entiende mejor.
    //la función map sirve para crear un nuevo array a partir de la anterior
    //más info https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

seleccion = prompt("Desea comprar estos servicios, escriba el nombre? \n 1 - seguro \n 2 - seguro2");

let elViajeDelServicio = packViajes.map((elViaje) => {
    elViaje.servicios.find(elServicio => elServicio.item == seleccion)
})

console.table(packViajes)
console.info(packViajesEditado)
console.log(seleccion)
console.log(elViajeDelServicio)

}
seleccionarServicios();
```

un par de cosas más:

1. como verás el console.log de la variable editado y de la última variable devuelve undefined, prueba por qué, puedes incluir console.log en cualquier sitio para ver como funciona y busca en la documentación oficial, como más se aprende es probando.
2. cuando solicites ayuda no pongas una foto porque para el que te va a ayudar supone pasar una foto a texto ;)

Comment: Excelente!! Ahora entiendo un poco mas la sintaxis y mis errores! sos un genio gracias!!